# Smart post format loop problems

Tags: post-formats

Hi i'm trying to adopt the `get_template_part()` method for looping post formats as in:

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        if( ! get_post_format() ) {
            get_template_part( 'format', 'standard' );
        } else {
            get_template_part( 'format', get_post_format() );
        }
    endwhile;
endif;
```

The theme i'm developing from [see files](https://github.com/wycks/WP-Skeleton-Theme) has an `index.php` file with the following calls

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage WP-Skeleton
 */

    get_header();  //the Header

    get_template_part( 'menu', 'index' ); //the  menu + logo/site title 

    get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' ); //the Loop  

    get_template_part( 'sidebar', 'index' ); //the Sidebar 

    get_footer(); //the Footer 

?>
```

loop.php is the main loop.

I'm not sure if I have to modify the index.php or loop.php files. I realise I have to create `format-audio.php`, `format-video.php` etc. for my various formats.

Whenever I try to get this going I get a continous loop of my posts.

Any help explaining this would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit format.php & format-*type*.php files according to your get_template_part() usage.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. Where do I put the get_template_part('format', get_post_format()); Does it replace get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' ); //the Loop ?

Comment: I would put the first code snippet you provided, which seems to be valid, in the index.php file (after get_header and before get_footer functions). Then I would create format.php (which would be for standard posts). Replace get_template_part( 'format', 'standard' ); with get_template_part( 'format '); and create format-*type*.php for each format. This way you don't even need loop.php.

Comment: I presume the format.php and format-*type*.php do not have to include the loop?

Comment: I've tryed your suggestion but am getting the continuous loop i.e its on an endless loop through my two test posts?

Comment: No loop. Just that first snippet you provided with the get_header and get_footer and the format & format-*type*.php files. Inside the format files, do not start a new loop, just start by echoing <?php the_title(); ?> for example, you'll get the hang of it.